# Adaptive Trigger equivalent in Avalonia UI

Tags: xaml, avalonia

We are trying to port some WPF code to Avalonia UI, we need to change the layout if the Grid width is greater than 1024

```
    <Style x:Key="ResponsiveGridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Grid" Binding="{Binding Path=Width, 
                                       Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, 
                                       Converter={StaticResource IsGreaterThanConverter}, 
                                       ConverterParameter=1024}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="MasterColumn" Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" Value="480"/>
                     <Setter TargetName="DetailColumn" Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" Value="*"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

The above code was done with a Data Trigger but how to do with an Avalonia UI selector
Here is what we have so far

customstyles.axaml

```
     <Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

      <Style  Selector="Grid.responsive#MasterColumn">
         <Setter Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" Value="480"/>
      </Style>
       <Style  Selector="Grid.responsive#DetailColumn">
         <Setter Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" Value="*"/>
     </Style>
 </Styles>
```

The grid we wish to apply the selectors to

```
  <Grid Classes="responsive" Background="White">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MasterColumn" Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DetailColumn" Width="0" />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: perhaps you're looking for  https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia.Xaml.Behaviors/blob/2f972ebb0066a2a4235126da7e103f684de1c777/samples/BehaviorsTestApplication.Base/Views/Pages/AdaptiveBehaviorView.axaml#L100-L139